# does `final` violate ODR?

Tags: c++11

```
// file1.cpp
struct Foo {
    virtual void boo() final;
};


// file2.cpp
struct Foo {
    virtual void boo();
};
```

Is this an ODR, or some other language rule violation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a violation of the ODR, as applied to the definition of `Foo`.

[basic.def.odr] paragraph 6:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type ... [or other entities frequently defined in header files] ... in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - ... [other rules to make sure all definitions have the same meaning in their context]

So any difference at all between class type definitions after preprocessing steps gives the program undefined behavior, even changing the name of an unused function parameter, changing `unsigned int` to `int unsigned`, or so on.